# Dayjs (and other browser based date libraries) returning wrong offsets when local browser time zone is changed

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, dayjs

I'm seeing some strange behavior that I don't really understand what is happening. I'm using Dayjs as a library and want to display user data based on the time zone that the user has specified on my app. In the below example, the user may be in `America/Chicago`, but the user specified `Africa/Accra` as their time zone, so all their data in my app will be in the `Africa/Accra` time zone.

Great, I simply use:

`dayjs.tz(1234567890, "Africa/Accra")`

Afterward, I can always do something like `dayjs.tz(1234567890, "Africa/Accra").offsetName()` to get the name of the time zone (in this case `Africa/Accra`, which is a `GMT` or `GMT+0` offset.

However, when I install a Chrome plugin to change my Chrome browser time zone (for example, https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/change-timezone-for-googl/cejckpjfigehbeecbbfhangbknpidcnh), and change to any time zone from the list, dayjs returns wrong time zone offset names.

It returns exclusively time zone offsets of the time zone specified by the browsere plugin. It completely ignores the time zone that I specify in the dayjs object.

For example, if I use that plugin to change the browser time zone to `America/Nassau`, `dayjs.tz(1234567890, "Africa/Accra").offsetName()` will return `GMT+7`, which is wrong. Refreshing the page to re-run the offsetName method will return a different offset name every time, so it's not even consistent.

I was under the assumption that dayjs will return the time zone offset that is inputted in the dayjs.tz function...which it always does. However, when I use this browser plugin, it doesn't and I do not know why.

Does anyone have any input? This behavior seems worrying to me and it's probably because I don't know what's going on.

Comment: If you can reproduce that, write a reproduction and open an issue on github if there's bo this issue yet

Comment: @Dimava I have it reproduced here: https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-pascal-tyc2mv?file=/src/DateTimePicker.js:1306-1322 Just make sure after you change the TZ with that plugin, refresh the codesandbox and see that luxon, datefns, etc all display different values when you change browser time zone. Only one that stays true is moment.

Comment: I'd assume that's a problem of this plugin which probably manipulates the `Date` class somehow. And  libraries building on the base of this `Date` may be the influenced as well.

Comment: And about the changing values: following the docs, the plugin you linked has the ability so set random timezones. Maybe you accidentally activated that setting?

Comment: also whats your local timezone? just to clarify?   I lean towards there being an issue with he plugin, but was looking through day.js and there are some outstanding issues/cases with how it handles the local time